# How do you save passwords safely on a server for a game?

Tags: java, file

So the question is what the title says. How can i store passwords safely so i can read and write to them but also other people cannot edit the files (with java)? FTP clearly wont work because you have to say the password.

Comment: This is far too broad. In general, though, you will want to hash your passwords, and maybe salt them. This will at least prevent them from being read should they get stolen.

Comment: i know about that but where can i store the passwords at? i am knowlegeable of hashing and salting (at least ive heard about it when trying to learn php)

Comment: As I said your question is too broad. It depends on your game server's architecture. It may make sense to store them in a database, or if that's overkill, in a flat file or XML file.

Comment: Well then, you know the answer to your own question.

Comment: is there  web server i can store it at and read it? i have tried using my weebly web site but no luck

Comment: is there any guy who will *** my brain harder that this one?

Answer (score 2):

> How do you save passwords safely on a server for a game?

The simple answer is DON'T.

- Don't store the password.
- Don't store it in the clear
- Don't store it encrypted
- Don't store it at all.

Design your system so that it is NOT NECESSARY to store use the user's password ... anywhere.

Instead, use strong crypto hashing algorithm AND a large random salt, and store the hash and the salt.  Try to store them securely, but the point is that if the security on your storage mechanism is broken then the hacker doesn't get the user's actual password.  And if your salting + hashing is string enough AND the user's choice of password is good enough then the chance of the hacker reverse engineering the password is small.

---

Also, it is unwise to rely on some other site to securely store your game server's passwords.  How do you know that *they* won't get hacked?  How do you know that they are trustworthy?

---

And if you really care about security, you should consider other means of authenticating your users.  Passwords are fundamentally a weak link. (This is probably overkill for a game, but I'm just saying ....)

---

> I wanted to know where to store the encrypted passwords.

Which part of *"Do not store it encrypted"* did you not understand?

If you rely on encryption, then you need to pick a strong encryption scheme, AND you need to solve the **really hard problem** of protecting the decryption key.  If you solve both of those problems properly, it doesn't matter where or how you solve the encrypted password.  If you don't then your password security is an illusion ... and worse.

> I'm not dumb. Your comment does not answer the question in any way whatsoever.

It is not a comment.  It is an answer.  And it is the only answer you are likely to get from someone who has half a clue about password security.  Managing fixed encryption / decryption keys is difficult.  How do you stop the bad guy from hacking into your computer and reading them off the disk drive?

If you don't like the advice, I suggest that you get some security text books and start reading up on the problem for yourself.

Comment: I wanted to know where to store the encrypted passwords. I'm not dumb. Your comment does not answer the question in any way whatsoever.